# iOS reuse a series of multiple views via storyboard

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard

In my app, I have a series of multiple view controllers, through which the user navigates sequentially to enter and submit his data (let's say "Overview", "Details", "Review Input", for example).

Now I need to reuse this flow in different parts of my app (e.g. user can create new data as well as edit existing data). Different articles (such as [this](http://cocoanuts.mobi/2014/03/26/reusable/) one) suggest isolating common parts into their own storyboard files for reuse. However, those strategies seem to target only single views instead of a sequence of views.

What would be the best strategy for sharing more complex flows, which consist of multiple views?